# How to obtain the maximum sum of the array with the following condition?

Tags: math, logic, dynamic-programming

Suppose the problem posed is as follows:

> On Mars there lives a colony of worms. Each worm is represented as elements in an 1D array. Worms decide to eat each other but **any worm can eat only its nearest neighbour**. Each worm has a preset amount of energy(*i.e the value of the element*). On Mars, the laws dictate that when a worm *i* with energy *x* eats another worm with energy *y*, the *i*-th worm’s final energy becomes ***x-y***. A worm is allowed to have negative energy levels.
>
> Find the maximum value of energy of the last standing worm.

```
Sample data:
0,-1,-1,-1,-1 has answer 4.
2,1,2,1 has answer 4.
```

What will be the suitable logic to address this problem?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, error messages, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for pointing out. I am new to the community. I will update. And also, I was not looking for a full code, but a logic or pseudo code!

Comment: What's wrong with brute force and testing all possibilities? Your first example has only `8*6*4*2 = 384` ways to get down to one worm, while your second has only `6*4*2 = 48` ways.

Comment: @RoryDaulton because we wont be running this on such small cases and its a good way to fail a job interview

Comment: @MitchelPaulin is this sarcasm or am I just dumb?!

Comment: @karthikeyan, can I ask from where you've found this problem. I'd like to test it if its from an online judge like hackerrank or codeforce..

Comment: @ShihabShahriar it was part of an hiring process for a company! And yes it was conducted by hacker rank. But I am not aware whether the question can be attempted now. But I simply couldn’t figure out any method to solve it. And hence brought me here!

Comment: @RoryDaulton can you please elaborate a bit on this brute force method? I don’t get what is 8*6*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has a surprisingly simple **O(N)** solution.

If **any** two members in the array have different signs, the answer is then sum of absolute values of all elements.

To see why, imagine a single positive value in the array, all other elements are negative (Example 1).  Now the best strategy would be keeping this value positive and gradually eating all neighbors away to increase this positive value. The position of the positive value doesn't matter. The strategy is same in case of a single negative element.

In more general case, if an array of size `N` have values of different signs, we can always find an array of size `N-1` with different signs, because there must be a pair of neighbors with different sign, which we can combine to form a number of any sign we prefer.

For example with this array : `[1,2,-5,4,-10]`

1. we can combine either (2,-5) or (4,-10). Lets combine (4,-10) to get `[1,2,-5,-14]`
2. We can only take (2,-5) now. So our array now is : `[1,-7,-14]`
3. Again only (1,-7) possible. But this time we have to keep combined value positive. So we are left with: `[8,-14]`
4. Final combining gives us `22`, sum of all absolute values.

In case of all values with same sign, our first move would be to produce an opposite sign combining a neighbor pair with as little "cost" as possible. Intuitively, we don't want to waste two big numbers on this conversion. If we take `x,y` neighbor pair, when combined the new value (of opposite sign) will be `abs(x-y)`. Since result is simply sum of absolute values, we can interpret it as - "loosing" `abs(x)` and `abs(y)` from maximum possible output and "gaining" `abs(x-y)` instead. So the "cost" for using this pair for sign conversion is `abs(x)+abs(y)-abs(x-y)`. Since we need to minimise this cost, we choose from initial array  neighbor pair that have lowest such value.

So if we take the above array but now all values are positive `[1,2,5,4,10]`:

1. "cost" of converting `(1,2)` to -1 is `1+2-abs(-1)=2`.
2. "cost" of converting `(2,5)` to -3 is `2+5-abs(-3)=4`.
3. "cost" of converting `(5,4)` to -1 is `5+4-abs(-1)=8`.
4. "cost" of converting `(4,10)` to -6 is `4+10-abs(-6)=8`.

So, we take and convert pair `(1,2)` to -1. Then just sum absolute values of resultant array to get 20. Notice that this value is exactly 2 less than our previous example.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I actually agree with you, let me try an edit to clarify

Comment: Your answer is much better now after your edit. Great ideas, +1!